# how can remove city name and update society name and save it into the database?

Tags: python, django

So I want to know how can I remove the city name from the society name and update the society name and save it into the database?

Below code is taking all the society names that contain the city name. but I want to update all the society's names and save them.

```
qs = Society.objects.all()
citys = City.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
clauses = (Q(name__iendswith=name) for name in citys)
query = reduce(operator.or_, clauses)
data = qs.filter(query)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I think the best idea will be to have a foreignkey on the Society model that refers to the City this will help you to avoid to add the city's name to the end of the society's name,have you tried that ?

Comment: No, I don't. So how can I remove the city name from society name?

Comment: the problem is that imagine you have society name `google_paris` and you want to remove `paris` then you have to slice the society name and remove the city name and after that update the society name  but this will take a long time if you have more data in the db.but if you have a foreignkey it will be very easy,

Comment: @Thierno Amadou Sow
In my case, I have spaces in society name `google paris` and I want to remove paris. So how can I do that? I used replace in `query` but it didn't work. `qs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(name__iendswith=name).replace('name', '') for name in citys)))` it shows me error: `AttributeError: 'Q' object has no attribute 'replace'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)I advice you to use my first comment in your question it is better to have a foreignkey for the city
2)Here is how you can achieve it without the foreignkey.

```
qs = Society.objects.all()
citys = City.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
clauses = (Q(name__iendswith=name) for name in citys)
query = reduce(operator.or_, clauses)
datas = qs.filter(query)
for data in datas:
    name = data.name
    new_name = " ".join(name.split()[:-1])
    data.name = new_name
    data.save()
```

this will do the trick but this is actually not a very good approach here is why:
let us say you have a company name `google paris` then new_name will be `google`,but let us 
assume you have `google new york city` then new_name will be `google new york` 
this is not actually what you want.
to make this work i advice you to add `#` before adding the city name something like
`google # paris` then the answer will be

```
qs = Society.objects.all()
citys = City.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
clauses = (Q(name__iendswith=name) for name in citys)
query = reduce(operator.or_, clauses)
datas = qs.filter(query)
for data in datas:
    name = data.name
    new_name = name.split('#')[0]
    data.name = new_name
    data.save()
```

This is just an idea how you can achieve it.

Comment: This second method adding `#` will not work for me. let me explain to you what am I actually want to do with this, I have this database containing these wrong entries like society names containing city names at the end so I just have to correct these data in my database.

Comment: @AkashSingh what about the first one ?

Comment: It's working for the case if I have a company name `google paris` then new_name will be `google`. but I have a second condition `google new york city` and I want to remove whole city name `new york city` from the end. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @AkashSingh is the company name always one word ?

Comment: No, it's not one word. Like it's named `Akshar Siddhi Heights Nerul Navi Mumbai` and in this `Nerul` is the locality name, `Navi Mumbai` is the city name. I want to remove the whole city name `Navi Mumbai` from the name. but as you said your second method is only removing the `Mumbai` from the name bcoz its index is `-1`.

Comment: @AkashSingh Sorry i do not know how to help you on that.